# Automate Pentaho job with sql agent

Tags: sql, pentaho

I am new in Pentaho. i have a couple of pentaho jobs that I want to call from MS sever sql agent and then schedule them on some specific times. Could you please provide with some step to step instruction on how to do this. I really appreciate your your help.

Comment: Have you seen the docs on `Kitchen` and `Pan`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "sql agent job"? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: OP refers to jobs as "package" and uses the name "SQL Agent" so I assume MS SQL Server.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant pentaho job. And I am using MS SQL sever 2012.